# Powershell to compare files

Tags: powershell

I am a new one to use powershell. Here I have one task to compare two files. The file format like this:

File A.txt

```
20160222|LineA
20160222|LineB
20160222|LineC
```

File B.txt

```
20160223|LineE
20160223|LineA
20160223|LineD
20160223|LineB
20130223|LineC
```

After comparing, I want to find out

```
20160223|LineE
20160223|LineD
```

as the third output file.

How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like the compressed date values are ignored during the compare, is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so this is a bit convoluted, but will get the job done.

```
# Split the date and value, but keep the raw value intact
$fileA = Get-Content .\fileA.txt | Select-Object -Property @{ Name="Value"; Expression={ $_.Substring($_.IndexOf("|")+1) }}, @{ Name="Raw"; Expression={ $_ }}
$fileB = Get-Content .\fileB.txt | Select-Object -Property @{ Name="Value"; Expression={ $_.Substring($_.IndexOf("|")+1) }}, @{ Name="Raw"; Expression={ $_ }}

# Find the differences, should contain LineE and LineD
$diffs = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fileA -DifferenceObject $fileB -Property Value | Select-Object -Expand Value

# Match the diffs against original content and pull out the raw values
$fileB | Where-Object { $diffs -contains $_.Value } | Select-Object -Expand Raw
```

Comment: Throws errors here for first 2 lines:
"ExpandProperty" needs System.String, $fileA is System.Object[]

Comment: But What if each line also contains delimiter "|" for example Line A = LineA1| LineA2, LineB = LineB1|LineB2 and so on. How can I find out 20160223|LineD1|lineD2 and 20160223|LineE1|lineE2

Comment: Updated to only split on initial `|`

Comment: I know the logic about your code, but there is an error on the "diffs = " line. Because fileA and fileB are array.

Comment: Hmm, i don't seem to have a problem with that line.  The powershell pipeline should handle the arrays appropriately.  What error are you receiving on that line?

Comment: Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null. BTW, your method is very brief and powerful but just has a little problem.

Comment: That error will occur if the $fileA parameter is null.  Do you have the correct file path for Get-Content?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104381/discussion-between-leo-and-cobster).

Comment: Thanks for Cobster's patient help!

Answer (score 1):

Thats more like the desired result :

```
$a = Import-Csv .\a.txt -Delimiter "|" -Header 'no', 'line'
$b = Import-Csv .\b.txt -Delimiter "|" -Header 'no', 'line'

$c = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b -Property line


$z =@()
foreach ($d in $c)
{
    if ($d.SideIndicator -eq "=>")
    {
        $z += $b | ?{$_.line -eq $d.line}
    }
    else  # <=
    {
        $z +=$a | ?{$_.line -eq $d.line}
    }
}
```

Result:

```
$z | % { write-host "$($_.no)|$($_.line)"}
20160223|LineE
20160223|LineD
```

Comment: the result is not LineD and LineE.

Comment: But What if each line also contains delimiter "|" for example Line A = LineA1| LineA2, LineB = LineB1|LineB2 and so on. How can I find out 20160223|LineD1|lineD2 and 20160223|LineE1|lineE2

Comment: Thats a different thing. You should got some code now to evolve to your special needs.